# Iterating over a list parsed over from a cvs. column

Tags: python, csv, parsing, tolist

I am trying to iterate over a list that contains temperatures. 
Appending the data/temperatures from a csv file to a list data structure was a not an issue. The problem occures when i want to count the occurences of temperatures above 6. I was print-testing.

I get an error due to the first element in the csv.column is a variable "SDK", which denotes the temperatures.  How can 'bypass' the first value ("SDK") in that column? As I only want/need to iterate over the integers.

The code:

```
def sunshine(file):
    with open(file,'r') as csv_file:
        lines = csv_file.readlines()

    temperaturesDays = []
    for line in lines:
        data = line.split(',')
        temperaturesDays.append(data[8])
    return temperaturesDays

    #print(temperaturesDays)


daily_sunshine_duration = sunshine('berlin.csv')
#print(daily_sunshine_duration) #works, print temps

for i in daily_sunshine_duration:
    if i < 6:
        print(i)
```

Comment: What do you mean "tried to int"? Can you give an example? See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Tried to int() the list, only I realized the column started with string "SDK". I figured out how to bypass that string with exception handling, thanks to @Jan. 
Only now the problem is that the list does not save all the elements (I suspect). There should be 365 elements, but only 71 get printed, which all are 0's except 2 elements in the list. Very Random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `data[8]` you do not only have integer values. You could either go for `try...except` as in:

```
temperaturesDays = []
for line in lines:
    data = line.split(',')
    try:
        temperaturesDays.append(int(data[8]))
    except:
        pass
return temperaturesDays
```

... or check/cast it elsewhere (e.g. `float(...)`, `isinstance(...)`).
Without real sample values it is hard to guess though.

Comment: i'm going to go ahead and delete my answer since this makes more sense given that OP has non-integer types in that column, it's possible OP is indexing the row wrong as well

Comment: That seemed to work, the output is not what I expected though. It does not iterate over the entire list, 365 days. I will have to figure it out. 

Thanks for the answers.